# derivative of loss function

Tags: maximum-likelihood, loss-functions, derivative

If we have a paralyzed loss function of the form of:
\begin{align}
L(\beta)& =\frac{1}{2}(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)+ 
\lambda \beta^T  f(\beta)
\end{align}
where $X_{n\times m}$ and $\beta_{m \times 1}$ and $f$ is considered as a column vector. Then what is the derivative of this function with respect to $\beta$. Note that it is derivative with respect to a vector.
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L(\beta)}{\partial \beta}& =\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)+ 
\lambda \beta^T  f(\beta)\bigg)
\end{align}

Sorry for the silly question. I just confused myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf)

From (84):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\bigg((y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)\bigg) & = -2 X^T(y-X\beta)
\end{align}
$$

And using (93):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\bigg(\lambda\beta^Tf(\beta)\bigg) &= \lambda \bigg( {\bigg[ \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \beta} \bigg]}^Tf(\beta) + \bigg[ \frac{\partial f(\beta)}{\partial \beta}\bigg]_{m\times m}^T\beta\bigg)
\\
 &= \lambda\bigg(I_{m \times m}f(\beta)+\bigg[ \frac{\partial f(\beta)}{\partial \beta}\bigg]_{m\times m}^T\beta_{m \times 1}\bigg)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This was what I guessed before but the problem is that the first part  (in your answer) is a $m\times 1$ vector and the second part is summation of a $m \times 1 $ and $1\times 1$ that is strange!

Comment: Edited. I was using column differentiation for the second part. Note that differentiation of a vector wrt vector is a matrix.